# How to restore caret position after CKEDITOR.inline in onclick event handler

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to initialize CKEditor instances in onclick event.
But I have a problem, that is in when it is just a div (contenteditrable) I can click on it and my caret will be at the position where I clicked.
But when CKEditor.inline function does its work, it moves the caret to the start of the container. I want to save caret position that was before CKEditor.inline and set it after.

I tried solutions like window.getSelection().anchor... tried various functions that allow us to save caret position and restore, but it has no effect.
Maybe there is some way to get anchorNode/anchorOffset/selectionStart and set them to CKEditor by its native commands?

```html
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello my name is ...</p>
  <p>I am from ...</p>
  <p>London is the capital of Great Britain</p>
</div>
```

```
const editor = document.getElementById('editor');
  let isActivated = false;
  let isContenteditable = false;

  editor.onmouseenter = function(e) {
    if (!isContenteditable) {
      isContenteditable = true;
      editor.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
    }
  };

  editor.onclick = function(e) {    
    if (!isActivated) {
      isActivated = true;
      const cke = CKEDITOR.inline('editor');

      cke.on('instanceReady', () => {
         // trying to set caret here
      });
    }
  }
```

have no idea how to pass caret through CKEditor initialization.
**the condition is mandatory that the initialization shouldn't be at the page loading because there are a lot of editors on one page and initializing of all isn't necessary. will lag**

use https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.4/standard/ckeditor.js

**PLAYGROUND** - bug reproduce https://codepen.io/medinsky/pen/zQpBJQ?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, but it seems that it is not very good.

Are there any other ideas?

https://codepen.io/medinsky/pen/Gaymxb?editors=0010

```
const isInRange = (position, start, end) => position >= start && position <= end;

function setCaretPosition(el, sPos) {
  let charIndex = 0;
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(el, 0);
  range.collapse(true);
  const nodeStack = [el];
  let node,
    foundStart = false,
    stop = false;

  while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      const nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
      if (!foundStart && isInRange(sPos, charIndex, nextCharIndex)) {
        range.setStart(node, sPos - charIndex);
        foundStart = true;
      }
      if (foundStart && isInRange(sPos, charIndex, nextCharIndex)) {
        range.setEnd(node, sPos - charIndex);
        stop = true;
      }
      charIndex = nextCharIndex;
    } else {
      let i = node.childNodes.length;
      while (i--) {
        nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}

const editor = document.getElementById('editor');
let isActivated = false;

editor.onclick = function(e) {

  if (!isActivated) {
    editor.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);

    const {anchorNode, anchorOffset} = window.getSelection();
    if (anchorNode && anchorOffset) {
       anchorNode.parentElement.setAttribute('data-bookmark', anchorOffset.toString());
    }

    isActivated = true;
    const cke = CKEDITOR.inline('editor', {
      extraAllowedContent: "*[data-bookmark]"
    });

    cke.on('instanceReady', () => {
      const bookmarkElement = cke.container.$.querySelector('[data-bookmark]');

      if (bookmarkElement) {
        const bookmarkOffset = bookmarkElement.dataset.bookmark;

        if (bookmarkOffset) {
          bookmarkElement.removeAttribute('data-bookmark');
          setCaretPosition(bookmarkElement, bookmarkOffset);
        }
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround worked great except that sometimes it didn't focus on the right sub node.

To fix this you need to not only store the anchorOffset in the parent, but also the text of the anchorNode.

And then modify the function to restore caret to something like this :

```
function restoreCaretPositionTo(el, sPos, origText) {
    console.log('el', el);
    let charIndex = 0;
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(el, 0);
    range.collapse(true);
    
    const nodeStack = [el];
    let node,
      foundStart = false,
      stop = false;
      

      let text, offset;
    
    while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
      if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      
         text = node.textContent || node.innerText;
    offset = text.indexOf(origText);
         
         
        const nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
       
        if (offset != -1 && !foundStart){ // && isInRange(sPos, charIndex, nextCharIndex)) {
            console.log('setting start', node, sPos);
            range.setStart(node, sPos);
          foundStart = true;
        }
        if (foundStart) {
          range.setEnd(node, sPos);
          stop = true;
        }
        charIndex = nextCharIndex;
      } else {
        let i = node.childNodes.length;
        while (i--) {
          nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
```